# Telegram bot in node inline_keyboard not working

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have been trying to send a basic inline keyboard with node to my bot doing this:

*Code*

```js
reply_markup: {
  inline_keyboard: [
    [
      {
        text: "Hi bro",
      },
      {
        text: "Sup men",
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

Curiously enough if I use **keyboard** instead of **inline_keyboard** it works perfectly (I still want the inline_keyboard) by only exchanging them in the code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton). "You must use exactly one of the optional fields." (it can be url, callback_data or others). A button with only "text" will not work.

```
  const opts = {
    reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [
          {
            text: "Hi bro",
            url: 'https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton' // You MUST use exactly one of the optional fields.
          },
          {
            text: "Sup men",
            url: 'https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton' // You MUST use exactly one of the optional fields.
          },
        ],
      ]
    }
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, 'test text', opts);
```

Comment: I need to add the url in the objects?

Comment: Not necessarily a url, "You must use exactly one of the optional fields." (it can be url, callback_data or others). A button with only "text" will not work.